# Long text can't be sent via $.getJSON

Tags: mysql, json

```
var shareContent = $("#txtshare").val();
                var vprivacy = $(".privacy:checked").val();
                if(shareContent!='') {
                        $.getJSON("../jsons/share.php",{txtshare : shareContent,privacy:vprivacy},function(json) {});
                }
```

When it reaches `$.getJSON` code wont go inside `function (json){}`. It works fine with short text. I've put the whole text directly in MySQL, but there was no error and everything worked fine. Why is this happening? Is there any constraint on sending text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET` has length limit, try to use `POST` instead.

```
$.post("../jsons/share.php",{txtshare : shareContent,privacy:vprivacy},function(json){}, 'json');
```

Comment: with `GET` I used `echo json_encode;` can I use json_encode for `POST` too?

Comment: @phpGeek It has nothing related with `json_encode`, you could use it with same way.